# Is there a wrapper for the TCPDump output in C or Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, c, wrapper, tcpdump

I'm writing a small utility in `Cocoa` and I need dissect the output of the `TCPDump` tool.
I began writing my own wrapper to convert the output of `TCPDump` into usable & meaningful classes and realized I can't be the first person to do this.

Does anyone know of a wrapper in `C` or `Objective-C` that analyzes the output of `TCPDump` and can help me get this done faster?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can use [libpcap](http://www.tcpdump.org/).

Comment: Thanks, I was hopping for something more basic which I can redistribute as part of my own utility. I don't suppoe there is anything like that? :)

Comment: I think (not sure though) you can distribute libpcap with your utility. That library has all the parsing functions you are looking for...

Comment: I'll look over the License and see :) Cheers mate

Comment: libpcap doesn't *have* to be redistributed, if your utility will be running on OS X; libpcap is a standard system library in OS X.

Comment: Note, however, that libpcap does no packet parsing whatsoever.  tcpdump and Wireshark use libpcap to *capture* traffic, but they include their own code to parse the packets.